# onStop() is being called right after onCreate()

Tags: android, android-activity

I need to use `onStop()` to free resources as bitmaps and bgms, and I'm facing the problem that `onStop()` takes too long to execute. So in the worst case scenario, the user would exit an activity and re-enter it  (in less than 1 second lets say), so the activity runs `onCreate()` and then it proceed to call `onStop()` (which I suppose it's called from when the user exited it).

So obviously, `onCreate()` is loading resources, but the `onStop()` call are freeing them right after, causing a null pointer exception.

Any possible solutions?

Comment: Are you sure onStop is called after onCreate? I think the Android prevents this from happening.

Comment: totally sure, tested it

Answer (score 0):

It's hackish, but you could work out how long it usually takes to free the resources and set a timer in `onCreate()` that waits until `onStop()` is surely done, then re-load any null resources. Almost surely there is a better solution, but if nothing else then you could do this.

Answer (score 0):

Tried this solution, but it's not the way I was planning to do this.

Since the error I'm getting is a `NullPointerException` caused by the fact that the late `onStop()` call is releasing every resourse loaded `onCreate()`, I'm just adding a `try-catch` block catching the `NullPointerException` and calling a function to reload the resources

Comment: In case you didn't think of this, that may not work unless you have a try-catch block for every single time you use each resource. If you do use it only the first time the resource is used, the possibility exists that it may be freed later.

Comment: I forgot to mention, that the program its an android game, so the catch block is in the engine thread, inside the run() method, so it kinda only need that call

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `onStart()` callback method to create all the resources that are released in `onStop()`, the problem will be resolved.

You get `NullPointerException` because you think `onCreate ()` is called but it is not.
`OnStop ()` can be called without the `Activity` be destroyed, in this case `onStart ()` is called instead of `onCreate()`, so, if the the resources been created in `onStart()`, this will prevent the `NullPointerException`.
See [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html)